# "ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0" for Tensorflow ONLY when using GUI

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, centos

I have the Centos7 minimal installation with the GNOME desktop installed on as well. I mainly use the terminal remotely but I use the GUI when working with the camera.

Here are the programs/packages that I use:

- Python 3.4.9
- Tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1
- Cuda 10.0
- Nvidia Drivers 481.56

When I am using the terminal and import tensorflow, everything runs as it should.

When I start up the GUI and try to import tensorflow on the GUIs terminal, I get the typical import error:

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Again, I do not get this error when I run it on the terminal WITHOUT the GUI. Even when I bring up the GUI and get this import error, I'll SSH into my machine and I'll still be able to import tensorflow on the SSH window.

My paths should be fine because, again, it successfully imports, just  not when importing it on the GUI. This is a really weird issue and I am completely lost as to why this is happening.

I have also tried various, compatible, versions of tensorflow and Cuda and other Desktops. I still get this issue.

I want to add that I recently reinstalled everything and just copied over my /home directory into the new installation. So before this, everything worked fine with or without the GUI.

Comment: I have had this exact same issue when SSH-ing into my Ubuntu 19.04 server from my Mac. If I ssh and run the commands myself it works, however if I run ssh via a script it fails and can't find libcublas.so.10.0. Asking for a non-pseudo terminal doesn't help, and installing XQuartz and using the `-X` or `-Y` option do not help either. I'm not sure if it is even GUI related since it works with manual user-interactive ssh.

Comment: This seems to be related to this [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi) however, none of their solutions work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. The error says that it could not find path to CUDA10 file (libcublas.so.10.0). However it is not complaining if you import TF on the SSH window. Is there any Firewalls or any restrictions acting when you open with GUI? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure... Is there a way to check for that? It does seem like the issue is the GUI. It is as if the the path to libcublas.so.10.0 cannot be reached through the GUI... Very strange.